# Is the Cirrus SR22T a turbo-prop? Or does in just have a turbocharger?

Tags: general-aviation, turboprop, engine-design

Is the Cirrus SR22T a turbo-prop? Or does in just have a turbocharger like in a car?

Comment: It is a turbocharged piston.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is a turbo charged piston aircraft (much like turbo charged car, the engine is somewhat similar to that [found in the older air cooled Porsche 911's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Porsche_PFM_3200) (think [930 turbo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Porsche_930))).

[Turboprop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turboprop) is generally short for Turbine-Propeller which is a propeller aircraft powered by a turbine engine.

Turbo charged piston aircraft are piston driven engines with a turbo charger, many often may carry the T or TC designation after the model number. Such as the [Piper Saratoga TC](https://www.aopa.org/news-and-media/all-news/2007/may/01/piper-saratoga-ii-tc) or [SR22T](https://cirrusaircraft.com/aircraft/sr22t/)

In this case we can reference the [SR22T's Specs from the website](https://cirrusaircraft.com/aircraft/sr22t/)

> **Airframe & Powerplant**
>
> [Continental TSIO-550-K](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continental_IO-550) 315 HP *Turbocharged Engine*